# nodejs net module tcp socket can't send data to hardware

Tags: node.js, tcp, wireshark

i have a hardware which communicates with an app (android) via tcp. Communication is captured with pcapdroid on the smartphone.

Now i try to build a node app that should communicate with the hardware (instead of android).

The problem is now the sending of data to the hardware(kemper amplifier).

```
const hexToString = (hex) => {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
    const hexValue = hex.substr(i, 2);
    const decimalValue = parseInt(hexValue, 16);
    str += String.fromCharCode(decimalValue);
  }
  return str;
};

const startHex = ["7b37374442364232" +
  "382d373835452d343634312d42383430" +
  "2d3432463046303641313146437d0d0a" +
  "7b33363946353045372d373530422d34" +
  "3539412d424145452d38354144443346" +
  "33373938447d0d0a7b32343930323732" +
  "452d434439322d344442412d41453332" +
  "2d4538414633374544334230417d0d0a" +
  "7b37373443444239452d373445442d34" +
  "3734302d414630392d41433936423341" +
  "36394131317d0d0a2e0d0a", "7b373734" +
  "43444239452d373445442d343734392d41" +
  "4630392d4143393642334136394131317d",
   "0d0a","0000000000000000"]



const socket = net.createConnection({port: 5727,host: "192.168.0.13"});


socket.on('data', data => {
   console.log("tcpserver client on data " + data);
   if (Buffer.from(data).toString('hex') === startHex[0]) {
    socket.write(Buffer.from(hexToString(startHex[1]),'utf-8'), (data) => {
      console.log("firstsend " + data);
     })
  }
})

socket.on('ready', () => {
   console.log("tcpserver client on ready " );
})

socket.on('error', (err) => {
   console.log("tcpserver client on error " + err );
})
```

the hardware doesn't seem to accept the data...(see attachment node_capture)

Noticed that

- my networkcard seems to prepend a header (does that matter)
- when using nodejs net module to mimic tcp send, the hardware appends (packet 10) a trailer '00' ???

node_capture: hardware sending data (network card header and trailer at the end -> see minimal pcap here: https://github.com/schoko11/wireshark/blob/main/node_capture.pcapng)

```
0000   **68 54 5a d0 d2 25 02 0c 43 01 08 72 08 00** 45 00   hTZ..%..C..r..E.
0010   00 cb 03 d8 00 00 ff 06 35 a5 c0 a8 00 0d c0 a8   ........5.......
0020   00 52 16 5f b3 cc 00 00 f4 53 ce 23 ad 82 50 18   .R._.....S.#..P.
0030   3e 4e 42 c2 00 00 7b 37 37 44 42 36 42 32 38 2d   >NB...{77DB6B28-
0040   37 38 35 45 2d 34 36 34 31 2d 42 38 34 30 2d 34   785E-4641-B840-4
0050   32 46 30 46 30 36 41 31 31 46 43 7d 0d 0a 7b 33   2F0F06A11FC}..{3
0060   36 39 46 35 30 45 37 2d 37 35 30 42 2d 34 35 39   69F50E7-750B-459
0070   41 2d 42 41 45 45 2d 38 35 41 44 44 33 46 33 37   A-BAEE-85ADD3F37
0080   39 38 44 7d 0d 0a 7b 32 34 39 30 32 37 32 45 2d   98D}..{2490272E-
0090   43 44 39 32 2d 34 44 42 41 2d 41 45 33 32 2d 45   CD92-4DBA-AE32-E
00a0   38 41 46 33 37 45 44 33 42 30 41 7d 0d 0a 7b 37   8AF37ED3B0A}..{7
00b0   37 34 43 44 42 39 45 2d 37 34 45 44 2d 34 37 34   74CDB9E-74ED-474
00c0   30 2d 41 46 30 39 2d 41 43 39 36 42 33 41 36 39   0-AF09-AC96B3A69
00d0   41 31 31 7d 0d 0a 2e 0d 0a **00**                     A11}......
```

node_capture: node is sending data:(causes tcp retransmission afterwards)

```
0000   **02 0c 43 01 08 72 68 54 5a d0 d2 25 08 00** 45 00   ..C..rhTZ..%..E.
0010   00 4e 25 ef 40 00 40 06 93 0b c0 a8 00 52 c0 a8   .N%.@.@......R..
0020   00 0d b3 cc 16 5f ce 23 ad 82 00 00 f4 f6 50 18   ....._.#......P.
0030   fa 4d 81 f0 00 00 7b 37 37 34 43 44 42 39 45 2d   .M....{774CDB9E-
0040   37 34 45 44 2d 34 37 34 39 2d 41 46 30 39 2d 41   74ED-4749-AF09-A
0050   43 39 36 42 33 41 36 39 41 31 31 7d               C96B3A69A11}
```

hardware_capture: hardware sending data (see minimal capture here: https://github.com/schoko11/wireshark/blob/main/wireshark_sample1.pcap):

```
0000   45 00 00 cb 00 00 40 00 40 06 c1 9f c0 a8 00 0d   E.....@.@.......
0010   0a d7 ad 01 16 5f b0 ce 77 eb 77 ec cc 3f 18 d2   ....._..w.w..?..
0020   50 18 04 00 24 41 00 00 7b 37 37 44 42 36 42 32   P...$A..{77DB6B2
0030   38 2d 37 38 35 45 2d 34 36 34 31 2d 42 38 34 30   8-785E-4641-B840
0040   2d 34 32 46 30 46 30 36 41 31 31 46 43 7d 0d 0a   -42F0F06A11FC}..
0050   7b 33 36 39 46 35 30 45 37 2d 37 35 30 42 2d 34   {369F50E7-750B-4
0060   35 39 41 2d 42 41 45 45 2d 38 35 41 44 44 33 46   59A-BAEE-85ADD3F
0070   33 37 39 38 44 7d 0d 0a 7b 32 34 39 30 32 37 32   3798D}..{2490272
0080   45 2d 43 44 39 32 2d 34 44 42 41 2d 41 45 33 32   E-CD92-4DBA-AE32
0090   2d 45 38 41 46 33 37 45 44 33 42 30 41 7d 0d 0a   -E8AF37ED3B0A}..
00a0   7b 37 37 34 43 44 42 39 45 2d 37 34 45 44 2d 34   {774CDB9E-74ED-4
00b0   37 34 30 2d 41 46 30 39 2d 41 43 39 36 42 33 41   740-AF09-AC96B3A
00c0   36 39 41 31 31 7d 0d 0a 2e 0d 0a                  69A11}.....
```

hardware_capture: android sending data:

```
0000   45 00 00 4e 6a c6 40 00 40 06 57 56 0a d7 ad 01   E..Nj.@.@.WV....
0010   c0 a8 00 0d b0 ce 16 5f cc 3f 18 d2 77 eb 78 8f   ......._.?..w.x.
0020   50 18 00 41 17 94 00 00 7b 37 37 34 43 44 42 39   P..A....{774CDB9
0030   45 2d 37 34 45 44 2d 34 37 34 30 2d 41 46 30 39   E-74ED-4740-AF09
0040   2d 41 43 39 36 42 33 41 36 39 41 31 31 7d         -AC96B3A69A11}
```

1. why do i get a tcp retransmission errors,
2. any advices to solve the problem

follow tcp stream in wireshark gives me this:

[wireshark_tcp_stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtZNI.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

wrong hex in starthex[1] silly me... otherwise everything fine now   :-(